# x as many as, where x is a number

Tags: phrase-usage

Do the following sentences make sense ?

> 1. They have produced 10 as many pianos this month as last month.
> 2. They have produced 10 pianos this month as many as last month.

I feel #2 is wrong, and can be expressed as `They have produced 10 pianos this month which are as many as last month`.

I know `twice as many as`, but never see `10(or any other number) as many as`

Comment: Actually, sentence 2 should be, “They have produced 10 pianos this month, which *is* as many as last month.”  The “is” refers to {the number they produced}, not {10}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is wrong, but the first one is just missing a "times".

So, the following is fine:

> They have produced 10 times as many pianos this month as last month.

This also fits to your experience of `twice as many as`, because `twice` stands for `two times`, as you can see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twice).